# Why are there only odd numbered harmonics in one closed end resonant tube?

Tags: waves, acoustics, boundary-conditions, resonance

1. Why do we only have odd numbered harmonics at one-end closed tubes, however, if we do a frequency spectrum we have some periodic spikes between the odd harmonic spikes, just like the picture below shows.
2. What do these "even" spikes mean?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Hint: You have to count nodes & antinodes of a [single closed end pipe](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/clocol.html).
2. The suppressed even harmonics presumably indicates that the actual "single closed end pipe" can behave partly like a second open end, i.e. an antinode.

Comment: Another hint: draw a picture of a closed tube, and show all of the harmonics that "fit" the tube.  The rules are: 1) a node MUST be at the closed end;  2) an antinode MUST be at the open end.  After drawing 3-4 different harmonics for a given tube, you'll see a pattern.